# Dynamic LINQ mechanism of PagedList works very slow

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, entity-framework-6, pagedlist

many months ago I created dynamic LINQ mechanism (Entity Framework) for returning PagedList, I believed it works good but when I made a test yesterday it was wrong. I inserted 10 000 records into single database's table. When I simply tried to take 10 first rows it took 9 seconds. The same for simple "Count()".

Here is my code:

```
                // loading set
                var query = context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();

                // including ref objects
                foreach (var include in pagedListFunc.Includes)
                {
                    query = query.Include(include);
                }

                // get Contains() clauses
                var whereClauses = PagedListHelper.GetPropertyWhereClauses<T>(pagedListFunc.SearchParameters, pagedListModel.QueryPhrase);

                var whereQuery = query.AsEnumerable();

                // add Contains() clauses to query
                if (whereClauses.Count > 0)
                {
                    whereQuery = whereQuery.Where(x => whereClauses.Any(w => w(x)));
                }

                if (pagedListFunc.EntryNarrows != null && pagedListFunc.EntryNarrows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var entryNarrow in pagedListFunc.EntryNarrows)
                    {
                        whereQuery = whereQuery.Where(entryNarrow);
                    }
                }

                // add additional filters
                foreach (var filter in pagedListModel.AdditionalFilters)
                {
                    var expression = PagedListHelper.GetAdditionalFilterClause<T>(filter);

                    if (expression != null)
                    {
                        whereQuery = whereQuery.Where(expression.Compile());
                    }
                }

                var orderParamFunc = PagedListHelper.GetPropertyFunc<T>(pagedListModel.OrderParameter.ParameterName);

                IOrderedEnumerable<T> finalQuery = pagedListModel.OrderParameter.OrderAscending ? whereQuery.OrderBy(orderParamFunc) : whereQuery.OrderByDescending(orderParamFunc);

                return finalQuery.ToPagedList(pagedListModel.PageNumber, pagedListModel.PageSize > 0 ? pagedListModel.PageSize : finalQuery.Count());
```

I tested Count() after every query / whereQuery change. It is working good until I create finalQuery with OrderBy - it is harshly slowing Count().

Funny thing is - when I wrote similar code to this dynamic code but working strictly on chosen DbSet it works very fast, as it should.

```
                    // custom query

                    Expression<Func<Dicts, string>> orderFunc = x => x.DictValue;
                    var customQuery = context.Dicts
                        .Include(x => x.AspNetUsers)
                        .Include(x => x.DictDomains);

                    customQuery = customQuery
                        .Where(x => x.DictDomains.DictDomainName.Contains(pagedListModel.QueryPhrase) ||
                                x.DictValue.Contains(pagedListModel.QueryPhrase) ||
                                x.DictDescription.Contains(pagedListModel.QueryPhrase) ||
                                x.AspNetUsers.UserName.Contains(pagedListModel.QueryPhrase) ||
                                x.DictCreateDate.ToString().Contains(pagedListModel.QueryPhrase));

                    var result =
                        pagedListModel.OrderParameter.OrderAscending ?
                        customQuery.OrderBy(orderFunc).ToPagedList(pagedListModel.PageNumber, pagedListModel.PageSize > 0 ? pagedListModel.PageSize : 0) :
                        customQuery.OrderByDescending(orderFunc).ToPagedList(pagedListModel.PageNumber, pagedListModel.PageSize > 0 ? pagedListModel.PageSize : 0);
```

This code gives me 10 records in less that a second. What am I doing wrong in my dynamic mechanism? Making "ToPagedList" on query which hasn't got OrderBy gives an error, anyway OrderBy/ToPagedList are very important for me.

Comment: Why do you apply `.AsEnumerable()`? Now you execute everything in memory after fetching *all* data from the database.

Comment: I saw that too, when I removed `var whereQuery = query.AsEnumerable();` and put everything inside `query` it works good until I do `IOrderedEnumerable<T> finalQuery = pagedListModel.OrderParameter.OrderAscending ? whereQuery.OrderBy(orderParamFunc) : whereQuery.OrderByDescending(orderParamFunc);`

Comment: That's because you also have `expression.Compile()`. Remove the `Compile`. It converts the expression into a `Func`, making the runtime address `whereQuery` as enumerable.

Comment: In my running example fortunately `pagedListModel.AdditionalFilters` is empty, so foreach doesn't run adding clauses into query. I still think the problem is OrderBy / OrderByDescending but I don't know why.

Comment: Probably. Just make sure you work with `Expression<Func>>` everywhere. No `Func<>`.

Comment: I will. I'm gonna write here on Monday if I figured something out. Thanks.